# Disable Azure Datastore download message

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any way to disable the warning presented whenever a file is loaded for the first time in Azure ML using datastores?

```
Downloaded path: /tmp/tmp5dto5vq4/path/to/file.txt is different from target path: /tmp/tmp5dto5vq4/path/to/file.txt
```

I connect to the Datastore following the azure tutorial:

```
ws = Workspace.from_config()
mounted_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace = ws, name = 'name')
mount_context = dataset.mount(mounted_path)

mount_context.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to find any official documentation or information about how to suppress warnings when new file loaded for the first time in Azure ML using datastores.

You can raise feature request - [Azure Machine Learning · Community](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/b9a0c624-ad25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f09d0)